# How do i set up javacc in intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javacc

I searched through the plugin repo and downloaded the javacc plugin.

Now that I have the plugin how do I use it in IntelliJ.

My project looks like this .

[image]

Comment: did you find any thing ??

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to embed JavaCC task into `Idea` gradle project (code snippet based on `kotlin` dsl):

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath("net.java.dev.javacc", "javacc", "7.0.10")
    }
}

sourceSets["main"].java.srcDir("src/main/javacc")

...
...
...

task("assembleJavacc") {
    val outDir = "$projectDir/src/main/javacc/your/gen/package/dir"
    doLast {
        arrayOf(
            "-JDK_VERSION=1.8", "-OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=$outDir",
            "$projectDir/src/main/resources/ParserDefinition.jj"
        ).also {
            JJTree().main(it).takeIf { rs -> rs == 0 }
                ?: throw RuntimeException("jjtree error: ${it.contentToString()}")
        }
        arrayOf("-OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=$outDir", "$outDir/ParserDefinition.jj.jj")
            .also {
                Main.mainProgram(it).takeIf { rs -> rs == 0 }
                    ?: throw RuntimeException("javacc error: ${it.contentToString()}")
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Responding to this a bit late, but maybe it can help someone. As far as I know the JavaCC Plugin for the IntelliJ IDEA only supports editing of files, not the generation of the Java files. For this you'll have to use the command line. Download [JavaCC](https://javacc.org/) and add the `bin` directory to your path. The `bin` directory should look something like this:

```
javacc      jjdoc       jjrun       jjtree.bat
javacc.bat  jjdoc.bat   jjtree      lib
```

where `lib` should contain your `javaccX.jar` file. Now you can generate your Java files from the command line:

```
javacc ./my-grammar-file.jj
```

Comment: there s no "bin" directory

Comment: @VeryGudJavaDev The name of `/bin` directory has apparently changed to `/scripts`. The procedure should still be the same though.

Answer (score -4):

In this case, select "Assignment3", right-click, choose "Open Module Settings", make sure "Assignment3" is selected in the center column.  In the right column, click the "Dependencies" tab and you will see a drop-down that is labeled "Module SDK:"  This is where you specify the JDK location.  Choose "New..." and if using a plug-in, choose "IntelliJ Platform Plugin SDK".  The pop-up will allow you to navigate to the location of the plug-in Java SDK you downloaded; be sure to choose the parent directory of the "bin", "jre", "lib", etc. directories, not the actual "bin" directory itself.  If however you had downloaded a JDK instead of a plug-in (I tend to favor external JDKs myself), you'd choose "JDK" instead, navigate to the JDK's parent-of-"bin",-etc. directory and choose that one.  Then click "OK" to make the selection.  Then click "Apply" and you will have set the JDK for your project module.

Comment: I answered this in 2015.  It's 2018 and we are a number of versions of IntelliJ ahead of whatever was current back then.  So re the above dirs, I can safely say they are out of date.